# Applying Change-of-variables to Conditional and Joint Densities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, change-of-variable

Suppose we have a conditional density $p(X|Y)$, and that we know $X = f(Z)$ for some function $f$ and a random variable $Z$.

Without the conditionals, we know that $p(X) = p(f^{-1}(X))|\det J(X)|$ where $J$ is the Jacobian of the inverse transform $f^{-1}$ by applying the change of variables theorem.

I am stuck on (maybe overthinking it) 
a) applying the change of variables to the conditional density $p(X|Y)$ 
b) the "reverse" case of applying it to $p(Y|X)$

Any references or explanations would be great

Comment: We can assume $f$ is monotonic, but $X$ and $Y$ are not independent

Comment: On $p(X \mid Y),$ the (random) variable $Y$ enters as a constant which you should treat as such when finding the new density in terms of $Z.$ At the end, you are finding $p(Z \mid Y).$